# How to label line chart with column from pandas dataframe (from 3rd column values)?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe, plot, label

I have a data set I filtered to the following (sample data):

```
Name Time l
1 1.129 1G-d
1 0.113 1G-a
1 3.374 1B-b
1 3.367 1B-c
1 3.374 1B-d
2 3.355 1B-e
2 3.361 1B-a
3 1.129 1G-a
```

I got this data after filtering the data frame and converting it to CSV file:

```py
# Assigns the new data frame to "df" with the data from only three columns
header = ['Names','Time','l']
df = pd.DataFrame(df_2, columns = header)

# Sorts the data frame by column "Names" as integers
df.Names = df.Names.astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Names'])

# Changes the data to match format after converting it to int
df.Time=df.Time.astype(int)
df.Time = df.Time/1000

csv_file = df.to_csv(index=False, columns=header, sep=" " )
```

Now, I am trying to graph lines for each label column data/items with markers. 
I want the column `l` as my line names (labels) - each as a new line, `Time` as my Y-axis values and `Names` as my X-axis values. 
So, in this case, I would have 7 different lines in the graph with these labels: `1G-d, 1G-a, 1B-b, 1B-c, 1B-d, 1B-e, 1B-a`.

I have done the following so far which is the additional settings, but I am not sure how to graph the lines.

```py
plt.xlim(0, 60)
plt.ylim(0, 18)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I used `sns.lineplot` which comes with hue and I do not want to have name for the label box. Also, in that case, I cannot have the markers without adding new column for style.

I also tried ply.plot but in that case, I am not sure how to have more lines. I can only give x and y values which create only one line.

If there's any other source, please let me know below.

Thanks

The final graph I want to have is like the following but with markers:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a few tweaks to seaborn's `lineplot`. Using some created data since your sample isn't really long enough to demonstrate:

```py
# Create data
np.random.seed(2019)
categories = ['1G-d', '1G-a', '1B-b', '1B-c', '1B-d', '1B-e', '1B-a']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':np.repeat(range(1,11), 10),
              'Time':np.random.randn(100).cumsum(),
              'l':np.random.choice(categories, 100)
        })

# Plot
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Name', y='Time', hue='l', style='l', dashes=False,
             markers=True, ci=None, err_style=None)

# Temporarily removing limits based on sample data
#plt.xlim(0, 60)
#plt.ylim(0, 18)

# Remove seaborn legend title & set new title (if desired)
ax = plt.gca()
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], title='New Title', loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

- To apply markers, you have to specify a `style` variable. This can be the same as `hue`.
- You likely want to remove `dashes`, `ci`, and `err_style`
- To remove the seaborn legend title, you can get the `handles` and `labels`, then re-add the legend without the first handle and label. You can also specify the location here and set a new title if desired (or just remove `title=...` for no title).

---

Edits per comments:

Filtering your data to only a subset of level categories can be done fairly easily via:

```py
categories = ['1G-d', '1G-a', '1B-b', '1B-c', '1B-d', '1B-e', '1B-a']
df = df.loc[df['l'].isin(categories)]
```

`markers=True` will fail if there are too many levels. If you are only interested in marking points for aesthetic purposes, you can simply multiply a single marker by the number of categories you are interested in (which you have already created to filter your data to categories of interest): `markers='o'*len(categories)`.

Alternatively, you can specify a custom dictionary to pass to the `markers` argument:

```py
points = ['o', '*', 'v', '^']
mult = len(categories) // len(points) + (len(categories) % len(points) > 0)
markers = {key:value for (key, value) 
           in zip(categories, points * mult)}
```

This will return a dictionary of category-point combinations, cycling over the marker points specified until each item in `categories` has a point style.

Comment: it is awesome! It is working with the small data I have. But once I try it with big data, it gives me the error below. I think it is because there are not as many symbols for lines as the data I have. how can I fix it but still have the lines with symbols in the markers? ```ValueError: These `style` levels are missing markers: {'1G-c', '10G-c', 'IB-f', '1G-b', '1G-d', '10G-b', 'IB-h', 'IB-g'}```

Comment: Also, could you please explain how can I make this line of the code shorter to filter the data? I cannot even divide it to two-line by pressing enter after comma: ```df=df.query('l=="IB-a" or l=="IB-b" or l=="IB-c" or l=="IB-d" or l=="IB-e" or l=="IB-f" or l=="IB-g" or l=="IB-h" or l=="1G-a" or l=="1G-b" or l=="1G-c" or l=="1G-d" or l=="10G-a" or l=="10G-b" or l=="10G-c" or l=="10G-d" ') ```

Comment: Correct -- `markers=True` will fail if there are too many levels. See edits to the answer (also addressing the second question).

Comment: Wow, It helped a lot! I updated the ```point``` to have more markers. But the technique is working. Thanks a lot! My last question is how does Removing seaborn legend title work? how does ax work there?

Comment: @r_e The seaborn legend title is actually a label (see [this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/seaborn-lineplot-13.png), where there are actually two 'titles'). So to remove it, you can get a list of each 'handle' and 'label' for the legend items, and slice away the first (0th) item.
`ax = plt.gca()` is just a convenience for getting the current axes object the figure is being plotted on, as the other methods rely on finding the handles/labels associated with and re-setting the legend for the current axes.

Comment: And you can certainly update `points` to have more markers. The illustration was that if you have more categories than points, you can modify the dictionary creation to ensure you loop back over the already-used points so that you don't get a 'style level missing markers' error.